# I already read my incoming messages on SO, but still I got the "1 Question Has 2 Answers" email the next day

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

In my prefs I've enabled "I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked". I got some answers to a question of mine, the envelope lighted up red when I visited SO again, I went and read the answers. The envelope became gray again. So you'd think SO knows that I've read the answers. But despite that, it sent me a notification mail the next day.